# sys.path.append("../../../") and sys.path.append("..")

Tags: python-3.x, sys.path

In one program, I noticed that author add two lines

```
sys.path.append("../../../")
sys.path.append("..")
```

Is the second `path.add` redundant?

Comment: The first one is the great-grandparent directory, and the second is the parent directory.  No they are not redundant.  Why would they be?

Comment: This `sys.path.append("../../../")` adds `"../../../"`, not `"../../"` and not `"../"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

".." moves you one level up in the directory tree from where you are. So multiple `..` moving you further up that many level.

Sys.path is a list of directories where the Python interpreter searches for modules. you may find through `print(sys.path)`. Please note it's a list.

The sys.path.append() method is used to append the path that we want to the existing list.

So second one is not redundant, you are the who added it...